# Send all traffic via proxy using iptables

Tags: iptables, wifi, ubuntu-16.04

I use ethernet for internet on which I need to use proxy (provided by collage to access internet which is 172.30.0.13:3128). Now I created a hotspot . Now any device connected to hotspot also need to configure proxy setting. I want to eliminate that by redirecting all request from all client to that proxy server how to do that.
I tried this which is not seems to be working.

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -i wlp2s0 -j DNAT --to 172.30.0.13:3128
```

Comment: 90% of http traffic is http**s** nowadays, tcp port 443, and can't be redirected easily.

Comment: but you can route almost everything using TOR and proxychains.